# Treeview prevent Node collapse

Tags: c#, .net, treeview, treenode

I have a .net 2.0 C# Project.
I have a Treeview with 2 Nodes, each of them has many child nodes.
When you click on a child node, a PDF is displayed in a webbrowser control depending on the properties of the node.
Fine, but the problem is that when both Nodes are expanded, and I click on a child node, the other node gets collapsed! I don't have any code that collapses any node of the treeview, but somehow it happens! I also had a look at the BeforeCollapse Event, but somehow it doesn't fire, alltough the other node collapses!

Can anyone imagine why this happens?
I would be very grateful if anyone can teach me how to prevent this happening!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I stopped using the WinForms TreeView some time ago because of it's limits and quirks.

My favorite replacement is the open-source TreeViewAdv:

[TreeViewAdv on Source Forge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/treeviewadv/)

[TreeViewAdv on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/treeviewadv.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the TVS_SINGLEEXPAND style is ON for the treeview. Try setting the HotTracking property to false.